# Hide a parent ID using jQuery/JavaScript in PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okay, I'm calling a PHP using Ajax for a file upload.

```
else if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed)=== false){
            echo '<script type = "text/javascript">window.alert("The only file types allowed are .jpg, .gif, .png");</script>';
            echo '<script type = "text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$.parent("#loadimg").fadeOut();});</script>';
        }
```

The alert works no problem but the second echo isn't working. It is not fadingOut the ID. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a selector to tell jQuery what to get the `parent()` of.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".childElement").parent("#loadimg").fadeOut();
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Note the first line of the first paragraph, "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements..."

If you're trying to fade out `#loadimg`, then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadimg").fadeOut();
});
```

And if you're trying to fade the parent of `#loadimg`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadimg").parent().fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the parent of what? Do you meant to remove all element with 'direct' parent of `#loading` ? Then i think its proper to use:

```
$('*').parent('#loading').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#loadimg').parent('div').fadeOut();
});
```

It would probably be easier to just give the parent div an id, then you could just do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#loadimg').fadeOut();
});
```